# How to change value of any column of semicolon separated csv file using python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Hi I am new in the Python. I want to change value of any column in semicolon separated CSV file. I have following CSV file format:

```
"S. No.";"name";"number";"status";
"1";"Mac";"54";"ABC";
"2";"Jack";"34";"xyz"; '''
```

I am using following Python code !Python code
!
[image]

However I am getting error "list index out of range".
I have search similar examples but most of them are comma separated CSV file. This code without delimiter specified is working fine for comma separated CSV file. I am getting row value like this
Row  `[" 1"; "Mac";" 54"; "ABC";]` so I can not able to access elements of row list. Please help me to sort out the issue.

Comment: Is this some kind of school assignment? SO is not the place to get your homework done..

Comment: can you post the code as text instead of in the form of a picture.

Comment: Sorry Peter I don't have idea about level of SO

Comment: Paste the exact input file content and  error stack trace. @Jitendra